# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3' Error when try to import sqlite3 and Django in Ubuntu

Tags: python, sqlite

I tried to Create Django Project. I'm able to create project but not able to run the `runserver` command. I got below error. I also tried to import sqlite3 got same error

```
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
>>>
```

Python version: Python 3.11.0

Comment: So why do you even mention Django!?

Comment: I got this error when I tried runserver, and I thought this is due to sqlite and tried to import sqlite got the same

Comment: Exactly, you got the same error without django/runserver.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't ship Python 3.11 yet. How did you install it? Did you build from source?

Comment: I suspect you built from source without having some optional dependencies installed, but unless you respond we can only guess.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is due to python being installed before sqlite3-dev .
You need to install sqlite3-dev
then reinstall python.

```
sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev
pyenv install 3.11.3
```

Source:

https://waylonwalker.com/pyenv-no-sqlite3/

Comment: Thank you so so much for providing the 'pyenv install' statement. Most answers say to 'rebuild' python. I have no idea what that means. Your answer got me moving forward. Endless blessings.

Comment: Gosh, this is gold! Scoured the internet for a solution and all of them just ask you to install some sort of sqlite package. Only this one totally fixes the issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris) suspected the Python 3.11 is causing the issues I don't know why but I just downgraded to 3.8.10 and it resolved the issue.